# Is there a difference between a "join table" and a "bridge table"?

Tags: terminology

I usually describe intermediate tables as "join tables", but I recently heard them referred to as "bridge tables".

Is there a difference between the two terms? I've researched the topic but have yet to find a satisfactory answer.

It seems like "join table" might be a generic term used to refer to either a "bridge table" or a "fact table". Is there any truth to that?

Comment: FWIW, the [Associative entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity) Wikipedia article mentions lots of synonymous terms for the subject, including *join table*, *bridge table* and ***intermediary** table*.